# Block any full screen App Android (ROOT)

Tags: android, root, statusbar, android-statusbar

I need to block full screen mode for any App started in Android. That mean App can be opened, but status bar must be visible. I tried to search a lot of info, but still not luck.
I found App that always showing status bar - but issue is, status bar have transparent color and full screen app is not attached screen, with that status bar.

I have root phone and can modify any settings, but can't update firmware. Also i tried to make overlay over screen, but still no luck, all app just ignore my overlay

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in *Xposed* framework in *App Settings* module:

http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings

Just set *Fullscreen* to *never* for every application that uses it.